# How to GROUP BY a calculated column in a query?

Tags: mysql, group-by, mariadb

I am trying to use `Case when` statements to label data based on conditions. Then I need to group the categories so that I am able to count them. I cannot use temp tables to do this task.

```
SELECT player_name,
       weight,
       CASE WHEN weight > 250 THEN 'over 250'
            WHEN weight > 200 AND weight <= 250 THEN '201-250'
            WHEN weight > 175 AND weight <= 200 THEN '176-200'
            ELSE '175 or under' END AS weight_group
  FROM benn.college_football_players
```

Output:

```
Over 250    10
201-250     50
176-200     3
```

etc.

Comment: explain better your question  .. the code seems correct  .. have you error? show error message.. wrong result show also you actual result  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the same `case` expression in the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN weight > 250 THEN 'over 250'
            WHEN weight > 200 AND weight <= 250 THEN '201-250'
            WHEN weight > 175 AND weight <= 200 THEN '176-200'
            ELSE '175 or under' END AS weight_group,
       COUNT(*)
FROM benn.college_football_players
GROUP BY CASE WHEN weight > 250 THEN 'over 250'
            WHEN weight > 200 AND weight <= 250 THEN '201-250'
            WHEN weight > 175 AND weight <= 200 THEN '176-200'
            ELSE '175 or under' END
```

Comment: (Shorter syntax:  `GROUP BY 1` -- meaning column 1.)

Comment: @RickJames agreed, this will work in MySQL, but this syntax is not supported by some other DBMSes and in my view should be avoided for portability.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a derived table (subselect) for group eg:

```
  select  t.weight_group, count(*) from (
    SELECT player_name,
           weight,
           CASE WHEN weight > 250 THEN 'over 250'
                WHEN weight > 200 AND weight <= 250 THEN '201-250'
                WHEN weight > 175 AND weight <= 200 THEN '176-200'
                ELSE '175 or under' END AS weight_group
      FROM benn.college_football_players

  ) t 
  group by weight_group
```